# How do I turn on port forwarding with Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, http

```
$ssh -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:80 localhost
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I don't have anything in my `~/.ssh` directory.

I'm logged in as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create key pair first.
do this:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```